# How to delete sms from inbox?

Tags: android, delphi, sms, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I've programmed an automatic sms responder:

```
.
.
.
function IsSMSAnswered(smsid: string): Boolean;
begin
  // Code to test if SMS is answered
end;

procedure SendReplySMS(reply_smssender, reply_smsbody: string);
begin
  // Code to send reply to smssender
end;

procedure FetchSMS;  //fetch sms used by timer every 1 minute
var
  cursor: JCursor;
  uri: Jnet_Uri;

  id_smsid: integer;
  id_smssender: integer;
  id_smsbody: integer;

  id_smsid: string;
  smssender: string;
  smsbody: string;
  smsreply: string;
begin
  uri:= StrToJURI('content://sms/inbox');
  cursor:= SharedActivity.getContentResolver.query(uri, nil, nil, nil, nil);

  id_smsid:= cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('_id'));
  id_smssender:= cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('address'));
  id_smsbody:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('body'));

  cursor.moveToLast;
  for i:= cursor.getCount downto 1 do
    begin
      smsid:= :=JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smsid));

      if not IsSMSAnswered(smsid) then
        begin
          smssender:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smssender));
          smsbody:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smssender));

          if smsbody = 'abc' then
            SendReplySMS(smssender, 'reply abc')
          else if smsbody = 'def' then
            SendReplySMS(smssender, 'reply def');
        end
      else
        Break;
    end;
end;
.
.
.
```

In this case remain all received sms messages in the phone database.

**How do I delete the received SMS message from the phone database after processing?**

```
.
.
.
if not IsSMSAnswered(smsid) then
  begin
    smssender:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smssender));
    smsbody:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smssender));

    if smsbody = 'abc' then
      SendReplySMS(smssender, 'reply abc')
    else if smsbody = 'def' then
      SendReplySMS(smssender, 'reply def');

    ???? Now do I delete this received message ????
  end
.
.
.
```

Comment: This solution is not for Delphi...

Comment: you can delete them in the very similar way you got them

Comment: how did you get them? what data abstraction did you use?

Comment: I got them from SharedActivity.getContentResolver.query - see code above.

Comment: great! so use a ContentResolver to delete them

Comment: OK. But can you show some little code how do it?

Comment: I have the solution, but I can answer my own question for 8 hours after asking ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a solution (with a little help by pskink):

```
.
.
.
procedure FetchSMS;  //fetch sms used by timer every 1 minute
var
  cursor: JCursor;
  uri: Jnet_Uri;
  uri_del: Jnet_Uri;

  id_smsid: integer;
  id_smssender: integer;
  id_smsbody: integer;

  smsid: string;
  smssender: string;
  smsbody: string;
  smsreply: string;
begin
  uri:= StrToJURI('content://sms/inbox');
 cursor:= SharedActivity.getContentResolver.query(uri, nil, nil, nil, nil);

  id_smsid:= cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('_id'));
  id_smssender:= cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('address'));
  id_smsbody:=cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('body'));

  cursor.moveToLast;
  for i:= cursor.getCount downto 1 do
    begin
      smsid:= :=JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smsid));

      if not IsSMSAnswered(smsid) then
        begin
          smssender:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smssender));
          smsbody:=JStringToString(cursor.getString(id_smssender));

          if smsbody = 'abc' then
            SendReplySMS(smssender, 'reply abc')
          else if smsbody = 'def' then
            SendReplySMS(smssender, 'reply def');

          // ???? Now I need to delete this received message ????

          // There is the answer
          uri_del:= StrToJURI('content://sms');
          SharedActivity.getContentResolver.delete(uri_del, StringToJString('_ID=' + smsid), nil);
          // There is the answer
        end
      else
        Break;
    end;
end;
```

.
.
.

Comment: Kudos for providing the solution, +1

Comment: My brain compiler tells me this won't compile due to doubled `id_smsid` variable.

Comment: Cursor.getColumnIndex always return integer value.

Comment: Could be. The issue I wanted to point out is that you have the `id_smsid` variable declared twice.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it and now it displays correctly.